# DataTables break on last "Next" or any "Previous" paginate button

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I have the following DataTable which calls **status_icons()** function for replacing 0 & 1 values with icons.

At first results page (**on initComplete**) I call status_icons() for the replacement and then I make a trigger out of DataTables scope in order to have my function re-executed for next paginated results due to DataTable DOM reconstruction behavor for each pagination.

The error I get is that **re-adds the status icons** over the current ones when you **you click on the "Previous"** button on any pagination or the numbered pagination boxes.

**My function for replacing values with icons**

```
function status_icons() {

    $('table tr').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('td').eq(0).text() == '1') {
            $(this).find('td').eq(0).replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-3 fa-check-circle-o datatable-paid-1"></i>');
        } else {
            $(this).find('td').eq(0).replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-3 fa-exclamation-circle datatable-paid-0"></i>');
        }
    });
}
```

**DataTable construction** - on initComplete calls the function for the first and second page results

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#invoices-table').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    columnDefs: [{ orderable: false, targets: [-1, -2, -3] }],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',  
    initComplete: function() {
      status_icons() // it executes my function for the first page of results
      var api = this.api();
      // some irrelevant code that uses api and does not cause my issue
      // ...

    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

**jQuery event** for executing my function each time a .paginate_button is clicked due to DataTable reconstruction

```
$(document).on('click','.paginate_button', function() {
  if( !$(this).hasClass("disabled") ){
    status_icons(); // it executes for the rest paginations
  }
});
```

> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wjqbbd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is a [really bad thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824549/should-all-jquery-events-be-bound-to-document) to delegate events to the `document` object. Furthermore, dataTables steals the click event totally, preventing you from adding additionally click event handlers to `.paginate_buttons`. A working event handler on a `.paginate_button` would be

```
$('body').on('mousedown','.paginate_button', function() {
  ...
})
```

However, your approach is somehow exaggerated or "wrong" in the context of what you want to achieve. dataTables have a [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) callback to deal with exact those issues. Simply add this to your `columDefs` section :

```
columnDefs: [
  { orderable: false, targets: [-1, -2, -3] },
  { targets : 0, 
    render: function(data, type) {
      if (type == 'display') {
        return data == '1' 
          ? '<i class="fa fa-3 fa-check-circle-o datatable-paid-1"></i>'
          : '<i class="fa fa-3 fa-exclamation-circle datatable-paid-0"></i>'
      } else {
        return data
      }
    }
  }
],
```

And you are good. It solves both problems: The one with lack of action on click, you dont have to worry on page changes at all - and the one with replicated font awesome icons inserted over and over.

It simply works by returning the correct `<i>` font awesome markup when dataTables want to *display* content for the column.

Have ported your code to a jsfiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2tzp19se/**

Comment: Good answer! +1... But is there any reason for the `setTimeout({...},0);` in the Fiddle?

Comment: hey @LouysPatriceBessette, no - just copy paste from OP's codepen. I just changed 1000ms to 0ms (because I really cannot see the reason for a timeout) but like to keep the code recognizeable for OP, so kept the original structure.

Comment: The only part I do not get in your answer is `targets: [-1, -2, -3]`. Can you explain? I'm sure, OP doesn't know either ;) Haaa... Forget it, I found. Those negative numbers are column indexes, counted from the right, to disable ordering.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, yes! This is also part of OP's original code. Have just changed the event handler (as an example of the first part in the answer) then commented `status_icons()` out and added a new `columnDefs` section targeting the first column.

Comment: Undoubtly your answer/solution gives extra value to the problem, great! Now `targets: 0` is for the first column, how it could be possible to put in this parameter an extra statement that pending on ` data == "1"` can affect also column 3,  let's say change its class to disabled. It seems not to give space for multiple statements that goes directly to other columns simultaneously

Comment: I transfered my question comment to new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282088/datatables-data-replacement-to-multiple-columns-based-on-ones-value

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/).

`.replaceWith()` does not only replace the `td` content...
But replaces the `td` itself with the passed argument (string or object).

Updated [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ZKdYzq?editors=1010)

Comment: Louys thanks for your response! Your solution fixes previous issue but causes a new one. When you go in the last results (Page 4 with 1's in status column) and then you go back (Page 3) then all the 1s lose their replacement font icon (green check) and render only the exclamation mark (the one which replaces the 0s)

Comment: I fixed it in the CodePen... I simply added a condition for the `else`. --- But to be honnest, the other answer is better than mine. ;)

Comment: Well it might.. but to be also honest you answered directly to what I asked so that makes your answer strictly directed and not lesser + it worked as well :)