# DataTables data replacement to multiple columns based on one's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to make a conditional statement which will replace data not only to the column that I target but also and on a second one based of selected target's value.

```
 setTimeout(function() {
  $('#invoices-table').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    columnDefs: [{ orderable: false, targets: [-1, -2, -3] }, {
      targets: 0, // statement is based on first column data
      render: function(data, type) {
        // if data in col0 is "1" then replace data in col0 and col5 (pay button)
        if (type == 'display' && data == '1') {
          return [
            { data: '<i class="fa fa-3 fa-check-circle-o datatable-paid-1"></i>', target: 0 },
            { data: '<button class="pay-btn btn btn-sm btn-success disabled">Paid</button>', target: 5 }
          ]
        } else {
          return [
            { data: '<i class="fa fa-3 fa-exclamation-circle datatable-paid-0"></i>', target: 0 }
          ]
        }
      },
    }],
    "lengthMenu": [
      [100, 5, 25, 50, -1],
      [100, 5, 25, 50, "All"]
    ],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    initComplete: function() {
      var api = this.api();
      // my actions upon complete
    }
  });
 }, 1500); // delay is needed due to needed time of mySQL for passing results
```

> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmgBdv?editors=0010

**EDIT**

Updated code both on post and codepen due to wrong target numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [**column.render**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) as suggested in previous answer, then you will see that the `render` callback have a few more params :

```
render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
```

Each section in `columnDefs` can have multiple targets, but `targets` is referring to *column indexes*, not data! So you have got this a little bit wrong. The meaning is : You can pass the same result string to multiple columns, i.e handling columns with for example checkboxes in one callback - but not distinguish between targets (columns) and different return strings in the same `columnDefs` section. That would not make so much sense, and would be really hard to implement.

Logically, if you want different values for different columns, then use different `columnDefs` sections. The `full` param hold all values for the row, so even you are targeting column #14 you can use `full` to inspect the value of column #0. Here is what you should do :

```
columnDefs: [
  { orderable: false, targets: [-1, -2, -3] }, 
  { targets: 0, 
    render: function(data, type) {
      if (type == 'display') {
        return data == '1' 
          ? '<i class="fa fa-3 fa-check-circle-o datatable-paid-1"></i>'
          : '<i class="fa fa-3 fa-exclamation-circle datatable-paid-0"></i>'
      } else {
         return data
      }
    }
  },
  { targets: 14, 
    render: function(data, type, full) {
      if (type == 'display') {
        return full[0] == '1' 
          ? '<button class="pay-btn btn btn-sm btn-success disabled">Paid</button>'
          : '<button class="pay-btn btn btn-sm btn-success">pay</button>'
      } else {
        return data
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: It works as you described, I see now on which logic was supposed to work. PS: just edited my post, I had wrong target numbers on the posted example, `target:14` (column 14) to `target:5`, if you may correct it too for the future readers ;-)

Comment: is `return full[0] == '1' ? '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-default disabled" >Paid</button>' : data` a correct method in case I want to keep what has been already generated by default in that column by my application in case "1" is not satisfied ?

Comment: Hey @VasilisKosmas, Yes, I will think so.  But you also have the upportunity not to prerender with `<button class="pay-btn btn btn-sm btn-success">pay</button> ` The column could just be empty, that would give less HTML to load in the first place.  If you have 500 rows, you will reduce the initial HTML with 60*500/1024 == 29kb.

Comment: davidkonrad actually the rows (fetched from DB for a NodeJS app) are even more than 500 depending on the search terms of the user's report, that is why I have to wrap the code inside a `setTimeout, 3000` so the DataTables are initiated after records have been fetched. The `"Pay"` button has to be displayed since it is an action button for marking current invoice/record as `"Paid"` (0) in the DB.